# Introducing randomness of time using cron and task queue

Tags: google-app-engine, scheduled-tasks

I'm looking for some engineering creativity to solve a problem on Google App Engine.

I have a small number of jobs that run periodically, but I'd like the jobs to be executed at random times. So instead of running a job every Tuesday at 2:00pm, I'd like it to run every Tuesday "between 2:00pm and 5:00pm".

Currently, I'm using the following algorithm...

1. Cron job runs every Tuesday at 2:00pm
2. The cron handler finds a list of specific jobs to run and creates a task queue event for each discrete task.
3. The respective task queue handler decides if it should actually run by picking a random number between one and N. If the random number is X, the job gets executed. Otherwise, it creates a new task queue event to try again. Each task has a maximum number of queue attempts to guarantee that the job actually completes at some point.

I've realized that another solution would be to create a task queue that has a very slow rate, and when the cron job fills the queue, it randomly re-orders the list of tasks before doing so.

Any ideas from App Engine users?

Comment: Can you elaborate? Does it need to occur at a different random time each day, or do you just want it to pick a time for each job and then run it daily? What do you mean "re-queue task queue jobs with a limit to the number of times I'll retry" - why are retries relevant?

Comment: @nick i edited the question and restated the current solution i have as well as posing an alternate solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a cron job at 2 pm that queues a task with a random countdown between 0 and 3 hours?

Comment: what task queue mechanism are you referring to as "a random countdown"?

Comment: create a random number between 0 and 10800 and pass it as a *countdown* task parameter http://code.google.com/intl/it/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/tasks.html

Comment: outstanding. i've been using task queues forever, but never noticed that parameter!? thank you!